# Which JQuery Charting library to use for multi plotting?

Tags: jquery, charts, plot

I have to plot this kind of chart using a JQuery Plugin.
So far I was using the [JQuery Visualize plugin](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update-to-jquery-visualize-accessible-charts-with-html5-from-designing-with.html) but I guess this is too complicated for it.

[image: Regression]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://hubscher.remy.free.fr/tally/images/2011/07/27/Regression557.jpg))</sub>

Do you have any idea of how to display the markers and the line in the same chart.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/scatter-chart/) in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at powerful [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library. It allows to do that thing.

Comment: Everything is configurable. This library is just awesome !

Comment: The only thing this library don't have is FLOSS licence. That's so bad, I will not be able to use it...

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [ZingChart](http://zingchart.com)... it has a chart type called "mixed" that allows you to plot many chart types in a single graphset.

(I'm on the ZingChart team... abegin [at] zingchart.com)

Andrew